# Methods to identify if the sequence converges or diverges

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Given a question asking us to decide whether a sequence divergences or convergences, I usually will first try to see if I can “let the sequence $a_n = f(x)$”, then I can use l’h Rule or just basic algebra to solve the limit (n to infinity) of $f(x)$ question then that’s also the limit for the sequence. If the first try failed I will try squeeze theorem. Is there any way to tell which method should I use before I start to calculate the limit?  What kind of questions are mostly solved by either method?

Comment: Evaluate the sequence and go with your instincts. Personally, I try to sketch the function in my head, and see what happens when $n$ gets large (as you do). There's essentially three cases; it converges, it diverges to infinity (or minus infinity), or it's bounded but doesn't converge. It's mostly experience that will help you determine which case it is.

Comment: Are there’s any cases that a sequence can’t be represented as a function to solve for coverngecy and divergency?

Comment: Yes, some sequences will be defined as for example $a_{2n}=\frac 1n$ and $a_{2n+1}=2^{-n}$ so you can't really write those as a function, but you can if you do the two cases separately. There's also functions that don't converge as a function, but do as a sequence; an easy example of that would be $a_n=\frac{\lfloor n\rfloor}{n}$. Again, it's just a matter of experience and evaluation/analysing skills that will make this easier for you